# Long strings and .find

Tags: excel, vba

I try to use the `.Find` method in the following code, but I get a "Type mismatch" error on this line:

```
Set Rng = SuchBereich.Find(What:=zelle.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)`
```

This is the procedure:

```
Sub test()

'Define Fields
Dim anzzeilen As Long
Dim SuchBereich As Range
Dim Bereich As Range
Dim t1 As Long
Dim t2 As Long

'Define SuchBereich as range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
anzzeilen = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set SuchBereich = .Range(.Cells(1, 5), .Cells(anzzeilen, 6))
End With

'Define Bereich as Range
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
t1 = .Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set Bereich = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(t1, 1))
End With

For Each zelle In Bereich
        If zelle.Value <> "" Then
            Set Rng = SuchBereich.Find(What:=zelle.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole) '<--ERROR
            'Debug.Print Rng.Address
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print zelle.Address
                zelle.Interior.ColorIndex = 12
            End If
        End If
Next zelle
End Sub
```

It always gives me the error "Type mismatch". I tried to use it with only figures in the cells and it works fine. If I use short strings (a, b, c...) it works as well but with my strings e.g.

> "SQL (Structured Query Language) is used to modify and access data or information from a storage area called database. This beginner online training sql tutorial website teaches you the basics of SQL code and train you how to write & program SQL queries. I will be sharing my database knowledge on SQL and help you learn programming SQL better. The concepts discussed in this SQL tutorial can be apply"

I always get the error. Could anyone help me doing the comparison above with `.Find` or can help me finding a proper alternative?

**What I am trying to achieve:**

- I have (on average) 100 comments on Workbook 1.
- I take a sample of 50 and copy them on sheet A of Workbook 2.
- Then I copy all comments on sheet B on Workbook 2 and close Workbook 1.
- Now I want to identify all sample comments (sheet A) on sheet B and highlight them by giving them another background colour.

Comment: On what line do you get this error? I'm not going to read your entire code to figure this out...

Comment: I get the error on: Set Rng = SuchBereich.Find(What:=zelle.Value, LookAt:=xlWhole)

Comment: Ok, well write that in your question, not a comment. Did it for you this time.

Comment: That example string of yours is 401 chars long! It looks like `Find` can only handle up to 256 chars. Do you really need to search for such long strings?? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have (on average) 100 comments on Workbook 1. I take a sample of 50 and copy them on sheet A of Workbook 2. Then I copy all comments on sheet B on Workbook 2 and close Workbook 1. Now I want to identify all sample comments (sheet A) on sheet B and highlight them by giving them another background colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example string of yours is 401 chars long. It looks like `Find` can only handle up to 256 chars.

One alternative is to search only for a substring that can uniquely identify each string. Could be e.g. the first 256 characters, or the last 256, or the middle 256, or whatever is long enough; probably doesn't even have to be 256 chars.